# DOMPDF Font Change

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, dompdf

Using DOM PDF to create some reports, however the only thing I am having problems with is setting a sans-serif font.

I have tried just about every way to set the font possible in CSS yet it always renders in a serif font.

I am not trying to render a custom font, just something simple like helvetica or arial.

Has anyone else had this issue or know why it may be defaulting to a serif?

Note: the application runs on CodeIgnitor.

Comment: If for some reason dompdf isn't getting the stylesheet it would default to serif (the default). Is the CSS part of your document, or in an external stylesheet? You can change the default font in the configuration (dompdf_custom_config.inc.php in v0.6.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can change to whatever font you want in dompdf_custom_config.inc.php file or you can specify font details how you will specify in a html and css file it will work. Becuase Dompdf allow css properties